Decent performing query to get the total count of all records that match some criteria, then paginate that?
I have a need to query paginated data. One of the requirements is to not only show the items on a given page, but also show the total number of items the user could view (supports page nav, as well as a notification to the user like "showing items 50-75 of 159"). I've seen a pattern across the code base I'm working on that I'm not really fond of; it basically amounts to inserting ALL data into a temp table then selecting out the specific data for the page then selecting out the count. It looks like this.
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllFoos] (   --Some parameters to filter the foos
                                        @PageIndex   INT = 1,
                                        @PageSize    INT = 25,
                                        @TotalCount  INT OUTPUT )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT --Some large number of fields
    INTO   #Foos
    FROM   [dbo].Foo
    WHERE  --Some condition is true

    SELECT @TotalCount = Count(1)
    FROM   #Foos;

    SELECT   *
    FROM     #Foos
    ORDER BY FooID 
    OFFSET ((@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END

The above queries the entire set of foos and gets all the data from them into a temp table. This might be hundreds or thousands of records, it then throws (by default) all but 25 of them away. This is a huge waste of compute. For my part, I've found a slightly better way to do it by looking at client statistics in SSMS
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllFoos] (   --Some other parameters to filter the foos
                                        @PageIndex   INT = 1,
                                        @PageSize    INT = 25,
                                        @TotalCount  INT OUTPUT )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT --Some large number of fields
    FROM   [dbo].Foo
    WHERE  --Some condition is true
    ORDER BY FooID 
    OFFSET ((@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

    SELECT @TotalCount = Count(1) 
    FROM [dbo].Foo
    WHERE  --Some condition is true
END

The first portion of the revised query, just selecting the rows I need with all the data takes less time by itself, but I ran into a problem that adding a secondary query added that time right back in. I was however able to mitigate that by adding an index to [dbo].Foo tailored around the criteria I wanted to query on, then it performed about 4 times faster (again, according to client statistics in ssms).
That said, I feel like all of this is pretty clunky -- I know sql is very low level, but is there some better way to accomplish this goal? A way I could do where clause filtering, get the count, then in a next step perform the offset ... rows / fetch next ... rows clause in a single operation? No matter what I try it seems like the query plan always shows two queries paths, sometimes against different indexes, but always two separate read operations. Below is an example of running the second query (with with real table/index names blurred out).


Whatever you do it's going to be inefficient to get the total count, because all rows must be read to do that. Why do you need it? The best you are going to get is to use ROW_NUMBER to filter all in a single query. And have you considered Keyset Pagination

Well that's a bummer, I might be able to use keyset pagination for some queries, but probably not all of them. I'll have to hassle my product owners.

Well it's impossible: how can you get the total number of rows without reading all the rows?

Maybe this solution would help https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-server-2005-paging-%e2%80%93-the-holy-grail

Will you consider estimates of  total number of items the user could view?  Or must it be an exact total?

as an option you can load select with where condition in to temp table and get your count and apply paging against temp table set

You can't "get the total" without actually reading all the rows.
The best you are going to get is to use window functions:
SELECT
  f.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      TotalCount = COUNT(*) OVER (),
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FooID)
    FROM [dbo].Foo
    WHERE  --Some condition is true
) f
WHERE f.RowNumber >= (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1
  AND f.RowNumber < @PageIndex * @PageSize;

Another option, as shown in this article and others, is to use opposing row-numbers. This usually means less IO, but requires a second sort.
SELECT
  Total = RowNumberRev + RowNumber - 1,
  f.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      RowNumberRev = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FooID DESC),
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FooID)
    FROM [dbo].Foo
    WHERE  --Some condition is true
) f
WHERE f.RowNumber >= (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1
  AND f.RowNumber < @PageIndex * @PageSize
ORDER BY
  RowNumber;

By choice I would probably forgo getting the total count. It's not actually necessary in the vast majority of cases.
To be honest, you would be better off using Keyset Pagination, it is far more efficient. You just jump to an ID (or start at the beginning) and read from there. No rows which are not being returned would actually be read.
See Is there any better option to apply pagination without applying OFFSET in SQL Server?
But this requires a radical rethink of the whole stack all the way to the UI. You wouldn't get the total number of rows, and you wouldn't page by row-number. So you can't show the user the number of pages, or even what page number they ar eon. It's like an infinite scrolling page, with just Previous and Next buttons.
